# How can I find probability of categorical variable?

Tags: python, r, probability

I have three columns in a dataset that tracks breaches in the USA. These are all discrete categorical variables. The dataset has 9k entries.

'State' tracks where the breach occurred. for example, VA, NY.

'Type of Breach' tracks, type of breach.Hacking, Fraud, etc.

'Type of Org' tracks the sector of the organization. 'MED' for medical

I am trying to find,

1. Probability of breach happening in VA for example, please note that VA appears 20 times in 'State' column. Would probability of VA be (total # of VA events/Total # of all outcomes) or 20/9000 = 0.002?
2. Same question for 'Type of Breach', trying to find the probability

3.'Type of Org', trying to find the probability of 'MED' being impacted by the breach.

Ultimately, if I want to find a probability of breach happening in VA, with hacking, and in MED sector..

Would it be like this? '0.002 * Probability of Type of Breach* Probability of 'Type of Org'?

I would love to know if there is an iterative library in python or R for this.

Comment: You're calculating the probability that, for a particular data breach, that the breach occurred in VA, with hacking, in the healthcare sector. What you probably *care about* is the probability that a specific organization will fall victim to a hack. That's not something you can figure out from your dataset without knowing how big your reference class is.

Comment: In `r` you can use the `table()` function to tabulate contingency tables of categorical variables. However, as @NickODell points out, this may not answer the real question at hand.

Comment: I agree with @NickODell. If you are still interested in finding the number of times VA occurs over the entire sample, there is a package `pandas` in `python`. A useful function is `value_counts()`, which counts the number of each `values` in the column.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Nick Odell, that is precisely what I am trying to find.

Let's say I am org X operating in the MEDICAL sector in VA. I want the macro probability so that we can have comparables. Kind of like earnings comparable to determine stock value.